# Many to Many, self join - how to do this, code first in Fluent Api, EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOvHl.png

So basically, I want to be able to define a User and have them be able to have a list of other Users that I designate as their friends - for some reason I'm stumped

Here are my classes and attempt so far:

```cs
public class User : BaseEntity, IUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid PhotoId { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public IList<ClubbrEvent> ClubbrEvents { get; set; }
    public bool ProfileComplete { get; set; }
    public List<UserFriends> Friends { get; set; }
    public List<UserFriends> FriendsOf { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class UserFriends
{
    public Long UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Long FriendId { get; set; }
    public User Friend { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class UserFriendsConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserFriends>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserFriends> builder)
    {


        builder.HasOne(f => f.Friend)
            .WithMany(fo => fo.FriendsOf)
            .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.FriendId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(u => u.User)
            .WithMany(f => f.Friends)
            .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId);
    }
}
```

But when I try to add a migration I get the following error:

*The entity type 'UserFriends' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943*.

Comment: What is "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, so leaving this here for anyone else in the same situation.

First, I had made a mistake in my join table properties - I had made them long but they should have been guid

Second, I defined the key in the config like so:

```
builder.HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.FriendId });
```

So in full:

```
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserFriends> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.FriendId });

            builder.HasOne(f => f.Friend)
                .WithMany(fo => fo.FriendsOf)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.FriendId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasOne(u => u.User)
                .WithMany(f => f.Friends)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId);
        }
```

Running the migration and update now gives me what I need:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkIo3.png